# Unsupported lookup 'incontains' for CharField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: django, django-orm

I am getting below Error while writing the Django ORM queryset :

Unsupported lookup 'incontains' for CharField or join on the field not permitted

I have tried the mentioned code to retrieve the query set

```
product =  Clothing.objects.filter(Q(product = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains =question).first())|Q(brand__icontains = question)| Q(category__icontains = question) | Q(sub_category__incontains = question) | Q(description__icontains = question))
```

I expect the Output Query should return the ouptut
but the actual output is "Unsupported lookup 'incontains' for CharField or join on the field not permitted"

Comment: You misspelled `icontains` as `incontains`.